# Not returning all possible one-step reductions for combinatory expressions

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

I'm trying to implement combinatory logic in Haskell, and am currently writing a function step, which returns a list of all possible one step reductions using the standard reduction rules. When running the step function on the variable S (S I) (K I) (S I K) I, it returns the correct expression for the first reduction, but when I reduce it again with step (head it) it returns only one of the possible reductions.

This is my code

```
module Main where

 data Combinator
  = I
  | K
  | S
  | V String
  | Combinator :@ Combinator
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

instance Show Combinator where
  show = f 0
    where
      f _ I = "I"
      f _ K = "K"
      f _ S = "S"
      f _ (V s) = s
      f i (c :@ d) = if i == 1 then "(" ++ s ++ ")" else s where s = f 0 c ++ " " ++ f 1 d

step :: Combinator -> [Combinator]
step (I :@ x) = [x]
step (K :@ x :@ y) = [x]
step (S :@ x :@ y :@ z) = [x :@ z :@ (y :@ z)]
step (c :@ d) = [c' :@ d | c' <- step c] ++ [c :@ d' | d' <- step d] ++ 
[c' :@ d' | c' <- step            c, d' <- step d]
step _ = []

parse :: String -> Combinator
parse s = down [] s
  where
    down [] (' ' : str) = down [] str
    down cs ('(' : str) = down (Nothing : cs) str
    down cs ('I' : str) = up cs I str
    down cs ('K' : str) = up cs K str
    down cs ('S' : str) = up cs S str
    down cs (c : str) = up cs (V [c]) str
    up [] c [] = c
    up (Just c : cs) d str = up cs (c :@ d) str
    up (Nothing : cs) d (')' : str) = up cs d str
    up cs d str = down (Just d : cs) str

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn $ "Combinatory Logic in Haskell"
```

I am aiming for this when running in GHCi-

```
*Main> parse "S(SI)(KI)(SIK)I"
S (S I) (K I) (S I K) I
*Main> step it
[S I (S I K) (K I (S I K)) I]
*Main> step (head it)
[ I (K I (S I K)) (S I K (K I (S I K))) I, S I (S I K) I I ]

I am getting -

ghci> parse "S(SI)(KI)(SIK)I"
S (S I) (K I) (S I K) I
ghci> step it
[S I (S I K) (K I (S I K)) I]
ghci> step (head it)
[I (K I (S I K)) (S I K (K I (S I K))) I]
```

Comment: The `(S :@ x :@ y :@ z)` case does not allow any reduction in `x`, `y`, or `z` to happen. The other cases have a similar issue. Note that the general `c :@ d` is not used when we fall in one of the earlier cases.

Comment: @chi that looks like an answer. Can you write it up as one? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> `[ I (K I (S I K)) (S I K (K I (S I K))) I, S I (S I K) I I ]`

This implies `step ((S :@ x :@ y :@ z) :@ I)` should produce `[s :@ I | s <- step (S :@ x :@ y :@ z)]`, which it does, by the last equation of `step`. However, if you want to explore only one step at a time, you should skip the `[c' :@ d' | …]` part of this equation, since it makes two steps in parallel.

It also implies `step (S :@ x :@ y :@ z)` should produce `[S :@ x :@ y :@ z' | z' <- step z]`, yet it doesn’t, because this is already matched by the third (S) equation of `step`.

In other words, your evaluator is slightly too lazy: it omits some of the steps that would be done by eager evaluation of arguments, since it only evaluates arguments if a call isn’t fully saturated.

One possible solution is to always visit each subexpression, *even* if reducing the whole application is possible; and separately consider whether the whole expression is reducible. This is perhaps easier to get right if we make `step` always step *exactly once*, returning an empty list if there is no single-step reduction.

```
step (f :@ z) = outer ++ left ++ right
  where

    --       I   z ~> z
    -- (  K   y) z ~> y
    -- ((S x) y) z ~> xz(yz)
    outer = case f of
      I -> [z]
      K :@ y -> [y]
      S :@ x :@ y -> [(x :@ z) :@ (y :@ z)]
      _ -> []

    --   f ~> f'
    -- -----------
    -- f z ~> f' z
    left = [f' :@ z | f' <- step f]

    --   z ~> z'
    -- -----------
    -- f z ~> f z'
    right = [f :@ z' | z' <- step z]    

step _ = []
```

Now `step` returns the result you expected, and you can compute the sequence of reductions using `iterate` and `concatMap` (or `=<<`).

```
λ import Data.List (nub)

λ reductions input = iterate (nub . concatMap step) [parse input]

λ import Data.Foldable (traverse_)

λ traverse_ print $ takeWhile (not . null) $ reductions "K(I(K(Ia)))bc"

[K (I (K (I a))) b c]
[I (K (I a)) c,K (K (I a)) b c,K (I (K a)) b c]
[K (I a) c,I (K a) c,K (K a) b c]
[I a,K a c]
[a]
```

I use `nub` here for illustration, to filter out duplicate solutions (confluent reductions), but I should point out that it’s very inefficient—not only because of `nub` itself, but also because of generating terms that will be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

The cases

```
step (I :@ x) = [x]
step (K :@ x :@ y) = [x]
step (S :@ x :@ y :@ z) = [x :@ z :@ (y :@ z)]
```

do not allow reductions within `x`, `y`, or `z`.

Note that the more general equation `step (c :@ d)` is not considered when we fall in one of the above cases.

Finally, I'm not sure if you really want `[c' :@ d' | c' <- step c, d' <- step d]` since that will perform two parallel steps.